# mvvm toolkit for small applications

Tags: wpf, mvvm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Starting WPF MVVM. Use a framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606883/starting-wpf-mvvm-use-a-framework) 
>   [What framework for MVVM should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use)

Hello all

I am looking for some easy toolkit for wpf beginner .

I am writing small applications and I am looking for something easy to begin.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use/1409740#1409740

Answer (score 4):

[MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)