# WPF: data validation of submit button

Tags: wpf, validation

Hi All I am very new to WPF and trying some sample
program to learn it.

**I have a application with following fields**

```
    Username(TextBox)

    Password(PasswordBox)

    Button(Submit)
```

**Requirement:**

I have to do the data validation of username and password.

```
1.Validation when the cursor moves from the Box.
```

and

```
2.Validation when the Submit is pressed.
```

To achieve both which Trigger needs to be used.
and how to acieve code for my second Requirement.

If you can share any sample code or direct me to some
link it will be very helpful.

Comment: Look at this  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574304/wpf-validation-how-to-show-tooltips-and-disable-run-button

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interface.

But, I'd definitely recommend looking into **`MVVM`** first. There are numerous frameworks built to help you:

- [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)
- [WAF (WPF Application Framework)](http://waf.codeplex.com/)
- [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com)
- [Silverlight.FX](http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX)
- [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)
- [Google Search](http://www.google.com/#q=MVVM+Toolkits) (In case you just want to find one on your own)
- [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use) (This discusses the different frameworks and their pros/cons).

**Good resources that use IDataErrorInfo:**

- [General Example](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/)
- [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)
- [John Dolinger's Video](http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv) (**MY FAVORITE** -- because he shows you how people normally do it, and how to change it to a nice MVVM pattern).