# MVVM framework AND Prism 4?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I just read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use). It has some nice answers, but they are over 1-year-old, and a lot have changed in this space over the last year. Some of the most popular frameworks have come out in a new mayor release such as Prism and MVVM Light Toolkit.

My question is somehow the same, but with one twist, I'm already using Prism 4.0 because of the region and module features.

Prism 4.0 embraces MVVM, but I feel there are some things which are "not lightweight", for instance interaction requests.
So I'm thinking would it better to use another MVVM framework either as a substitute or a supplement for Prism 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to stop you using an MVVM framework in addition to Prism.  We're using Caliburn.Micro and Prism - there is some crossover in functionality provided, and many differences too.  Use whatever tool is most appropriate for the problem you're solving.

Answer (score 1):

MVVMLight is quickly becoming the standard MVVM Implementation. In particular due to its multi platform support (wpf, silverlight, wp7), extreme blendability, and exactly the stuff you need to make MVVM applications ... nothing more ... nothing less.

Comment: Yes it does. Prism is a super-set of MVVMLight and MVVMLight makes an effort to seamlessly plug into prism e.g. the IOC used in MVVMLight is plug-able into Prism.