# Implementing Tab Control Pages Ribbon Tab using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, user-controls, ribbon

I am creating an Application which will be a Tab based application having separate pages for each Tab. I want use RibbonTab as the Tab.

On selecting one RibbonTab corresponding UserControl will be loaded in the below section.
Each RibbonTab and each UserControl should behave like a pair.

First Challenge - It would be easy to use single ViewModel for each RibbonTab-UserControl pair. But how to share single ViewwModel in to separate view.

Second Challenge - What is best way to implement this application

One Ribbontab and One UserControl is already ready. Waiting for how to associate those two.

Comment: if it is easy to use single viewmodel for each tab - which is right - why would you complicate things ? however if you need to share/transfer data between viewmodels , you can use mvvmlight messenger class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the First challenge could you elaborate it please and I'll edit the answer.

As for the second challenge I highly recomend choosing a framework as that will make implementing MVVM a little easier [Framework Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use)

I use a ContentControl and ResourceDictionary to determine what view to display based on the bound ViewModel as in [this](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/) example. That technique could be used for the tab control as well here are a couple links on how to implement this:

[Microsoft Tab Controled application Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

[Tab Control Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651542/901395)

Comment: I programmed it out in pure MVVM. Check this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2OckuDTLwnZ86p50Keyh_67zz2eWwFC/view?usp=sharing