# WPF FullScreen (MDI) but not MDI

Tags: c#, wpf

I am redesigning my WinForms application using WPF, I was only 2 weeks in to the project and quickly learn't that many of the controls I needed would require custom controls while WPF allows me to design these easily.

So far I have a MainWindow.xaml, Login.xaml and Menu.xaml,

The idea is to display the login, upon verification show the menu then if that closes back to login inside the main window which would be full screen.

To get the functionality working I simply created the login and menu forms with the WindowStyle="none" and centered it to the screen, this obviously doesn't work because there is still a form but not linked to the main form.

In winforms I used MDI but reading this forum and looking at question MDI is frowned on, I looked at tab controls.  So far I can find tutorials on using 1 form to display it but can not find a suitable tutorial for going login>menu>login

I don't want to be spoonfed, this project is just a practice project to try and get to grips with WPF but there are a lot of questions relating to the subject and everyone handles it differently it seams.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really happy to hear this. WPF Rocks. .Net Developers should embrace it. You will not regret this decision =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating an overly complex answer, and without including concepts that are obviously new to you such as [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)(s) or [WindowManager](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/)(s), this is a bare bones example of a Fullscreen application showing many different "sub windows" (which are not windows per se, but rather UserControls)

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="FullScreenAppSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStyle="None">
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowLogin()
    {
        var loginview = new LoginView();
        this.Content = loginview;
    }

    private void ShowMenu()
    {
        var menu = new MenuView();
        this.Content = menu;
    }
}
```

LoginView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FullScreenAppSample.Login.LoginView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <!-- your login screen UI here -->
</UserControl>
```

MenuView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FullScreenAppSample.Menu.MenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <!-- your Menu UI here -->
</UserControl>
```

This is what could be called a "View First" approach, where the View dictates the "flow" of the application by taking the responsibility of instantiating other views and making them visible.

---

That being said, I'll take a minute to address your assertion that

> everyone handles it differently

Yes. The mainstream approach to creating WPF applications is something called [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085), which was conceived as a WPF-specific version of [Martin Fowler's Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html). There are, however, many interpretations and many different versions of MVVM out there, together with many [MVVM Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using), such as [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), and Microsoft's [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (amongst many others).

Each of these frameworks provide the basic tooling (base classes, helper classes, services, abstractions, event aggregators and whatnot) to ease the development of large-scale, complex WPF applications.

Bottom line: there is not a definitive "right way" to handle things like View and ViewModel instantiantion / management in WPF, that will depend on your [choice of MVVM Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409740/643085) and the specifics of your project, such as need for testability.

I, personally, have taken various parts and components (and concepts, too) from several different frameworks and composed my own, ViewModel-first MVVM approach. I would recommend that you take some time to analyze your project requirements and consider whether using any of these.

Comment: Hey again, I took your advice and after seeing the beauty of the other code decided to approach and learn WPF.  I assume on main window load I would call login? to show it, seams to work just want to make sure I called it correctly!

Thanks

Comment: @JamesSmithyCleave yes, pretty much. Though you will probably need to put your login logic and call to services into a `ViewModel`, and not in code behind. That's the point of the second part of this answer, that you should not put business logic in code behind.

Comment: Thanks guess I need to take a step back and look at some tutorials on MVVM, I am very familiar with cakephp and other frameworks which use the whole Model View Controller so the idea isn't foreign to me!

Comment: there doesn't seam to be any sort of message feature on here, do you hang out anywhere chat wise?  Need to go through my winforms application to understand something, I have about 30 forms at the moment and not entirely sure whether I should have 30 views etc, seams a bit overkill!

Comment: @JamesSmithyCleave yeah find me in SO chat. Why would you thing 30 views is overkill? I just counted and our application here has 1102 `.xaml` files, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Any chance you can create a room and invite me, can only see you in some what looks like private rooms, just got a few questions to iron out before diving in to WPF :)

Comment: @JamesSmithyCleave See you in [ChatRoom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38365/room-for-highcore-and-james-smithy-cleave)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of "forms" and "windows" think of how you might design this application as if it were a web application. The login "screen" can simply be a user control laid on top of everything else that prevents the user from interacting with any of the controls below while it is displayed.

Also don't reference controls within each other directly. Instead add events to each of your user controls and bind them to the appropriate methods in other controls in your MainWindow.