# Visual Studio Project Template for MVC Windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In Visual studio , when we try to create a new project , MVC Project templates are listed for web application like ASP.NET MVC3 web application , ASP.NET MVC4 web application. Is there any project template provided by Microsoft to implement MVC for windows application. If I would like to implement MVC on Windows application , how should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no out-of-the-box templates for Windows applications based on the MVC pattern, simply because **the MVC pattern is not recommended for Windows applications**.

Modern Windows UI technologies (such as WPF and WinRT XAML (aka Windows Store Apps)) **are much better suited for the [MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)** rather than MVC.

There is [**a myriad of MVVM Frameworks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409553/what-framework-for-mvvm-should-i-use) available for Windows applications, most of them have full support for WPF and WinRT, and even Silverlight and Windows Phone.

In particular, [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx), which is the Official MVVM Framework from Microsoft, is available as a [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PrismMVVMLibrary) and includes some default Project Templates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to implement MVC on Windows application , how should I start

There are no templates out-of-the-box.  You'll have to create your own.

Comment: A little bit more of background information might help the OP. Such as mentioning that the preferred pattern for Windows applications is MVVM rather than MVC and that there's an [Official MVVM Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) available.

Comment: As I haven't developed any .Net UI non-web based application in quite a long time, my knowledge is limited in this area, so I stuck with answering the question directly without any additional information.  You comment is great for future readers.